# importing data from csv file, should I read it like excel file?

Tags: java, excel, file, csv

I'm writing a java program to read data from csv file and store it in the database.
I got confused a little.
If I open the respective csv file, it opens with microsoft excel.
So, while reading from this csv file, should i read based on ',' or ';' (like in csv file),
or should I read like as it in a excel file (column by column) ?

```
String cvsSplitBy = ",";

br =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){

            String[] row = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            String value1 = row[1];
         }
```

Am I doing it correctly? Or should I change it excel reading fashion ?

Comment: why do u want to re-invent the wheel when there are csvreaders/writers avaialble

Comment: @JunedAhsan This project is like already existing and kinda huge. I should do this functionality with the existing resources.

Comment: in this URL you can find a useful example of reading CSV file  http://www.journaldev.com/2544/java-csv-parserwriter-example-using-opencsv-apache-commons-csv-and-supercsv

Comment: @esprittn Thanks. I've seen those tutorials. I understood the code also. But like I asked my real question is about 'should I consider it as a an excel or a acsv file'

Comment: Excel can read and write a CSV file. Your file is CSV so you should consider it as a CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

A CSV file is a text file basically. MS Excel can read and write CSV files and it uses the separators in a CSV file (like , or ;) to do the display in the form of table. But reading a CSV file using dedicated parsers/streams is advantageous as CSV is more than just a text file with separators.

For e.g. if ';' is the separator, then a string with ',' should not be split into two rows. Also if there is string as data, (e.g. if a column data is "Fun;Enjoy" - including the double quotes) then you don't want the string to be split as "Fun and Enjoy" in two different columns. Such sophistications are possible only using CSV parsers/streams(custom classes that you can create if you want or already existing ones)

Answer (score 0):

You do it wrong. Your code will work with only small subset of CSV

Try it with next file

```
First value, "Second value", "Third, but not last", "and you will be surprised
how agile CSV is"
```

This data contain two lines, but only one CSV row. And value in third column contains comma. Last value consist of two lines.

So you better use real parser, if you not ready to handle all that cases (and possibly more)

Answer (score 0):

CSV can be separated by anything, the most popular is comma, but it does not necessarily needs to be a coma. A CSV file is a matrix (or table) where the columns are separated by a given separator (usually a comma).

For example [SalesForce sample csv is a comma](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_asynch/Content/datafiles_csv_sample_file.htm).

However excel let's you select if you try to import a file:

```
, ; | \t
```

In the above image, you can see how the avaliable separators on the excel import wizard
[image]